# LNK2019: unresolved external symbol - linking .h files with .cpp (definition) files in Visual Studio 2022 isn't working

Tags: c++, visual-studio, inheritance, linker

Okay, so I'm currently a beginner programmer for C++ (year 11 in school, 3rd year of high school but we're still studying basic functions, so please excuse any rookie mistakes) and I'm learning additional coding knowledge by myself. Context aside, I moved to Visual Studio 2022 and I'm following a course, currently learning about Inheritance.

Thing is, I have a project with a base Account class and 3 other publicly derived classes (from the Account class) and each of these have headers and definition files, but whenever I try to run the main I get the following error chain:

```
1>SectionChallenge.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "void __cdecl deposit(class std::vector<class Account,class std::allocator<class Account> > const &,double)" (?deposit@@YAXAEBV?$vector@VAccount@@V?$allocator@VAccount@@@std@@@std@@N@Z) referenced in function main
1>  Hint on symbols that are defined and could potentially match:
1>    "void __cdecl deposit(class std::vector<class Account,class std::allocator<class Account> > &,double)" (?deposit@@YAXAEAV?$vector@VAccount@@V?$allocator@VAccount@@@std@@@std@@N@Z)
1>    "void __cdecl deposit(class std::vector<class CheckingAccount,class std::allocator<class CheckingAccount> > &,double)" (?deposit@@YAXAEAV?$vector@VCheckingAccount@@V?$allocator@VCheckingAccount@@@std@@@std@@N@Z)
1>    "void __cdecl deposit(class std::vector<class SavingsAccount,class std::allocator<class SavingsAccount> > &,double)" (?deposit@@YAXAEAV?$vector@VSavingsAccount@@V?$allocator@VSavingsAccount@@@std@@@std@@N@Z)
1>    "void __cdecl deposit(class std::vector<class TrustAccount,class std::allocator<class TrustAccount> > &,double)" (?deposit@@YAXAEAV?$vector@VTrustAccount@@V?$allocator@VTrustAccount@@@std@@@std@@N@Z)
1>    "public: bool __cdecl Account::deposit(double)" (?deposit@Account@@QEAA_NN@Z)
1>    "public: bool __cdecl SavingsAccount::deposit(double)" (?deposit@SavingsAccount@@QEAA_NN@Z)
1>    "public: bool __cdecl TrustAccount::deposit(double)" (?deposit@TrustAccount@@QEAA_NN@Z)
1>SectionChallenge.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "void __cdecl withdraw(class std::vector<class Account,class std::allocator<class Account> > const &,double)" (?withdraw@@YAXAEBV?$vector@VAccount@@V?$allocator@VAccount@@@std@@@std@@N@Z) referenced in function main
1>  Hint on symbols that are defined and could potentially match:
1>    "void __cdecl withdraw(class std::vector<class Account,class std::allocator<class Account> > &,double)" (?withdraw@@YAXAEAV?$vector@VAccount@@V?$allocator@VAccount@@@std@@@std@@N@Z)
1>    "void __cdecl withdraw(class std::vector<class CheckingAccount,class std::allocator<class CheckingAccount> > &,double)" (?withdraw@@YAXAEAV?$vector@VCheckingAccount@@V?$allocator@VCheckingAccount@@@std@@@std@@N@Z)
1>    "void __cdecl withdraw(class std::vector<class SavingsAccount,class std::allocator<class SavingsAccount> > &,double)" (?withdraw@@YAXAEAV?$vector@VSavingsAccount@@V?$allocator@VSavingsAccount@@@std@@@std@@N@Z)
1>    "void __cdecl withdraw(class std::vector<class TrustAccount,class std::allocator<class TrustAccount> > &,double)" (?withdraw@@YAXAEAV?$vector@VTrustAccount@@V?$allocator@VTrustAccount@@@std@@@std@@N@Z)
1>    "public: bool __cdecl Account::withdraw(double)" (?withdraw@Account@@QEAA_NN@Z)
1>    "public: bool __cdecl CheckingAccount::withdraw(double)" (?withdraw@CheckingAccount@@QEAA_NN@Z)
1>    "public: bool __cdecl TrustAccount::withdraw(double)" (?withdraw@TrustAccount@@QEAA_NN@Z)
1>SectionChallenge.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "void __cdecl deposit(class std::vector<class SavingsAccount,class std::allocator<class SavingsAccount> > const &,double)" (?deposit@@YAXAEBV?$vector@VSavingsAccount@@V?$allocator@VSavingsAccount@@@std@@@std@@N@Z) referenced in function main
1>  Hint on symbols that are defined and could potentially match:
1>    "void __cdecl deposit(class std::vector<class Account,class std::allocator<class Account> > &,double)" (?deposit@@YAXAEAV?$vector@VAccount@@V?$allocator@VAccount@@@std@@@std@@N@Z)
1>    "void __cdecl deposit(class std::vector<class CheckingAccount,class std::allocator<class CheckingAccount> > &,double)" (?deposit@@YAXAEAV?$vector@VCheckingAccount@@V?$allocator@VCheckingAccount@@@std@@@std@@N@Z)
1>    "void __cdecl deposit(class std::vector<class SavingsAccount,class std::allocator<class SavingsAccount> > &,double)" (?deposit@@YAXAEAV?$vector@VSavingsAccount@@V?$allocator@VSavingsAccount@@@std@@@std@@N@Z)
1>    "void __cdecl deposit(class std::vector<class TrustAccount,class std::allocator<class TrustAccount> > &,double)" (?deposit@@YAXAEAV?$vector@VTrustAccount@@V?$allocator@VTrustAccount@@@std@@@std@@N@Z)
1>    "public: bool __cdecl Account::deposit(double)" (?deposit@Account@@QEAA_NN@Z)
1>    "public: bool __cdecl SavingsAccount::deposit(double)" (?deposit@SavingsAccount@@QEAA_NN@Z)
1>    "public: bool __cdecl TrustAccount::deposit(double)" (?deposit@TrustAccount@@QEAA_NN@Z)
1>SectionChallenge.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "void __cdecl withdraw(class std::vector<class SavingsAccount,class std::allocator<class SavingsAccount> > const &,double)" (?withdraw@@YAXAEBV?$vector@VSavingsAccount@@V?$allocator@VSavingsAccount@@@std@@@std@@N@Z) referenced in function main
1>  Hint on symbols that are defined and could potentially match:
1>    "void __cdecl withdraw(class std::vector<class Account,class std::allocator<class Account> > &,double)" (?withdraw@@YAXAEAV?$vector@VAccount@@V?$allocator@VAccount@@@std@@@std@@N@Z)
1>    "void __cdecl withdraw(class std::vector<class CheckingAccount,class std::allocator<class CheckingAccount> > &,double)" (?withdraw@@YAXAEAV?$vector@VCheckingAccount@@V?$allocator@VCheckingAccount@@@std@@@std@@N@Z)
1>    "void __cdecl withdraw(class std::vector<class SavingsAccount,class std::allocator<class SavingsAccount> > &,double)" (?withdraw@@YAXAEAV?$vector@VSavingsAccount@@V?$allocator@VSavingsAccount@@@std@@@std@@N@Z)
1>    "void __cdecl withdraw(class std::vector<class TrustAccount,class std::allocator<class TrustAccount> > &,double)" (?withdraw@@YAXAEAV?$vector@VTrustAccount@@V?$allocator@VTrustAccount@@@std@@@std@@N@Z)
1>    "public: bool __cdecl Account::withdraw(double)" (?withdraw@Account@@QEAA_NN@Z)
1>    "public: bool __cdecl CheckingAccount::withdraw(double)" (?withdraw@CheckingAccount@@QEAA_NN@Z)
1>    "public: bool __cdecl TrustAccount::withdraw(double)" (?withdraw@TrustAccount@@QEAA_NN@Z)
1>SectionChallenge.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "void __cdecl deposit(class std::vector<class CheckingAccount,class std::allocator<class CheckingAccount> > const &,double)" (?deposit@@YAXAEBV?$vector@VCheckingAccount@@V?$allocator@VCheckingAccount@@@std@@@std@@N@Z) referenced in function main
1>  Hint on symbols that are defined and could potentially match:
1>    "void __cdecl deposit(class std::vector<class Account,class std::allocator<class Account> > &,double)" (?deposit@@YAXAEAV?$vector@VAccount@@V?$allocator@VAccount@@@std@@@std@@N@Z)
1>    "void __cdecl deposit(class std::vector<class CheckingAccount,class std::allocator<class CheckingAccount> > &,double)" (?deposit@@YAXAEAV?$vector@VCheckingAccount@@V?$allocator@VCheckingAccount@@@std@@@std@@N@Z)
1>    "void __cdecl deposit(class std::vector<class SavingsAccount,class std::allocator<class SavingsAccount> > &,double)" (?deposit@@YAXAEAV?$vector@VSavingsAccount@@V?$allocator@VSavingsAccount@@@std@@@std@@N@Z)
1>    "void __cdecl deposit(class std::vector<class TrustAccount,class std::allocator<class TrustAccount> > &,double)" (?deposit@@YAXAEAV?$vector@VTrustAccount@@V?$allocator@VTrustAccount@@@std@@@std@@N@Z)
1>    "public: bool __cdecl Account::deposit(double)" (?deposit@Account@@QEAA_NN@Z)
1>    "public: bool __cdecl SavingsAccount::deposit(double)" (?deposit@SavingsAccount@@QEAA_NN@Z)
1>    "public: bool __cdecl TrustAccount::deposit(double)" (?deposit@TrustAccount@@QEAA_NN@Z)
1>SectionChallenge.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "void __cdecl withdraw(class std::vector<class CheckingAccount,class std::allocator<class CheckingAccount> > const &,double)" (?withdraw@@YAXAEBV?$vector@VCheckingAccount@@V?$allocator@VCheckingAccount@@@std@@@std@@N@Z) referenced in function main
1>  Hint on symbols that are defined and could potentially match:
1>    "void __cdecl withdraw(class std::vector<class Account,class std::allocator<class Account> > &,double)" (?withdraw@@YAXAEAV?$vector@VAccount@@V?$allocator@VAccount@@@std@@@std@@N@Z)
1>    "void __cdecl withdraw(class std::vector<class CheckingAccount,class std::allocator<class CheckingAccount> > &,double)" (?withdraw@@YAXAEAV?$vector@VCheckingAccount@@V?$allocator@VCheckingAccount@@@std@@@std@@N@Z)
1>    "void __cdecl withdraw(class std::vector<class SavingsAccount,class std::allocator<class SavingsAccount> > &,double)" (?withdraw@@YAXAEAV?$vector@VSavingsAccount@@V?$allocator@VSavingsAccount@@@std@@@std@@N@Z)
1>    "void __cdecl withdraw(class std::vector<class TrustAccount,class std::allocator<class TrustAccount> > &,double)" (?withdraw@@YAXAEAV?$vector@VTrustAccount@@V?$allocator@VTrustAccount@@@std@@@std@@N@Z)
1>    "public: bool __cdecl Account::withdraw(double)" (?withdraw@Account@@QEAA_NN@Z)
1>    "public: bool __cdecl CheckingAccount::withdraw(double)" (?withdraw@CheckingAccount@@QEAA_NN@Z)
1>    "public: bool __cdecl TrustAccount::withdraw(double)" (?withdraw@TrustAccount@@QEAA_NN@Z)
1>SectionChallenge.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "void __cdecl deposit(class std::vector<class TrustAccount,class std::allocator<class TrustAccount> > const &,double)" (?deposit@@YAXAEBV?$vector@VTrustAccount@@V?$allocator@VTrustAccount@@@std@@@std@@N@Z) referenced in function main
1>  Hint on symbols that are defined and could potentially match:
1>    "void __cdecl deposit(class std::vector<class Account,class std::allocator<class Account> > &,double)" (?deposit@@YAXAEAV?$vector@VAccount@@V?$allocator@VAccount@@@std@@@std@@N@Z)
1>    "void __cdecl deposit(class std::vector<class CheckingAccount,class std::allocator<class CheckingAccount> > &,double)" (?deposit@@YAXAEAV?$vector@VCheckingAccount@@V?$allocator@VCheckingAccount@@@std@@@std@@N@Z)
1>    "void __cdecl deposit(class std::vector<class SavingsAccount,class std::allocator<class SavingsAccount> > &,double)" (?deposit@@YAXAEAV?$vector@VSavingsAccount@@V?$allocator@VSavingsAccount@@@std@@@std@@N@Z)
1>    "void __cdecl deposit(class std::vector<class TrustAccount,class std::allocator<class TrustAccount> > &,double)" (?deposit@@YAXAEAV?$vector@VTrustAccount@@V?$allocator@VTrustAccount@@@std@@@std@@N@Z)
1>    "public: bool __cdecl Account::deposit(double)" (?deposit@Account@@QEAA_NN@Z)
1>    "public: bool __cdecl SavingsAccount::deposit(double)" (?deposit@SavingsAccount@@QEAA_NN@Z)
1>    "public: bool __cdecl TrustAccount::deposit(double)" (?deposit@TrustAccount@@QEAA_NN@Z)
1>SectionChallenge.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "void __cdecl withdraw(class std::vector<class TrustAccount,class std::allocator<class TrustAccount> > const &,double)" (?withdraw@@YAXAEBV?$vector@VTrustAccount@@V?$allocator@VTrustAccount@@@std@@@std@@N@Z) referenced in function main
1>  Hint on symbols that are defined and could potentially match:
1>    "void __cdecl withdraw(class std::vector<class Account,class std::allocator<class Account> > &,double)" (?withdraw@@YAXAEAV?$vector@VAccount@@V?$allocator@VAccount@@@std@@@std@@N@Z)
1>    "void __cdecl withdraw(class std::vector<class CheckingAccount,class std::allocator<class CheckingAccount> > &,double)" (?withdraw@@YAXAEAV?$vector@VCheckingAccount@@V?$allocator@VCheckingAccount@@@std@@@std@@N@Z)
1>    "void __cdecl withdraw(class std::vector<class SavingsAccount,class std::allocator<class SavingsAccount> > &,double)" (?withdraw@@YAXAEAV?$vector@VSavingsAccount@@V?$allocator@VSavingsAccount@@@std@@@std@@N@Z)
1>    "void __cdecl withdraw(class std::vector<class TrustAccount,class std::allocator<class TrustAccount> > &,double)" (?withdraw@@YAXAEAV?$vector@VTrustAccount@@V?$allocator@VTrustAccount@@@std@@@std@@N@Z)
1>    "public: bool __cdecl Account::withdraw(double)" (?withdraw@Account@@QEAA_NN@Z)
1>    "public: bool __cdecl CheckingAccount::withdraw(double)" (?withdraw@CheckingAccount@@QEAA_NN@Z)
1>    "public: bool __cdecl TrustAccount::withdraw(double)" (?withdraw@TrustAccount@@QEAA_NN@Z)
1>C:\Users\Sapok\Desktop\Programming_projects\Visual Studio\ConstructorsAndDestructors\x64\Debug\3. Inheritance - DerivingClasses.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 8 unresolved externals
```

From what I've gathered, the compiler is either pissed that it hasn't found any definitions for the functions I declared in the headers, or it's pissed that it can't tell apart between the "deposit" and "withdraw" functions for each class (each class has those 2 methods and they're named the same everywhere, but inheritance should make it work fine, I've checked the code itself and no other compiler errors appear). At this point, I'm genuinely stumped as to what the hell the compiler's crying about and how to fix it.

I've tried to include all the headers in all the files, all the .cpp files everywhere. Including the .cpp files only makes it spit out the LNK1169 (multiply defined symbols) instead, so no bueno. I've tried copying everything to a fresh solution and to no avail, I've double and triple checked all the code, I've tried moving files around, I've scoured a number of posts talking about this same type of error and none of them seem to help.

(A screenshot of my project's file distribution):
https://i.stack.imgur.com/gOXym.png

For example's sake, here's my base Account class header...

```
#ifndef _ACCOUNT_H_
#define _ACCOUNT_H_
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

class Account {
    friend std::ostream& operator<< (std::ostream &out, const Account& account);
private:
    static constexpr const char* def_name = "Unnamed account";
    static constexpr double def_balance = 0.0;
protected:
    std::string name;
    double balance;
public:
    Account(std::string name = def_name, double balance = def_balance);
    bool deposit(double amount);
    bool withdraw(double amount);
};

#endif // _ACCOUNT_H_
```

...and its definition .cpp file.

```
#include "Account.h"
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

Account::Account(std::string name, double balance)
    : name{ name }, balance{ balance } {}

bool Account::deposit(double amount) {
    if (amount < 0)
        return false;
    else {
        balance += amount;
        return true;
    }
}

bool Account::withdraw(double amount) {
    if (balance - amount < 0)
        return false;
    else {
        balance -= amount;
        return true;
    }
}

std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& out, const Account& account) {
    out << "[Account: " << account.name << ": " << account.balance << "]";
    return out;
}
```

All the other classes are very similar, as inheritance usually works.

Sorry for the long-winded explanation, I'm still new to all this and I just wanna make sure I get all the necessary details across. If anyone has any general etiquette tips for help posts like this one, that'd be greatly appreciated as well :)

Thanks in advance!

Edit: I'll include all the code - I think this isn't clear enough.

Account.h and Account.cpp are included above

SavingsAccount.h:

```
#ifndef _SAVINGSACCOUNT_H_
#define _SAVINGSACCOUNT_H_
#include "Account.h"
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

class SavingsAccount : public Account{
    friend std::ostream& operator<< (std::ostream& out, const SavingsAccount& account);
private:
    static constexpr const char* def_name = "Unnamed account";
    static constexpr double def_balance = 0.0;
    static constexpr double def_interest = 0.0;
protected:
    double interest;
public:
    SavingsAccount(std::string name = def_name, double balance = def_balance, double interest = def_interest);
    bool deposit(double amount);
    // Inherited withdraw
};

#endif // _SAVINGSACCOUNT_H_
```

SavingsAccount.cpp:

```
#include "SavingsAccount.h"
#include "Account.h"
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

SavingsAccount::SavingsAccount(std::string name, double balance, double interest)
    : Account(name, balance), interest{ interest } {}

bool SavingsAccount::deposit(double amount) {
    amount += amount * (interest / 100);
    return Account::deposit(amount);
}

std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& out, const SavingsAccount& account) {
    out << "[SavingsAccount: " << account.name << ": " << account.balance << ", " << account.interest << "%]";
    return out;
}
```

CheckingAccount.h:

```
#ifndef _CHECKINGACCOUNT_H_
#define _CHECKINGACCOUNT_H_
#include "Account.h"
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

class CheckingAccount : public Account {
    friend std::ostream& operator<< (std::ostream& out, const CheckingAccount& account);
private:
    static constexpr const char* def_name = "Unnamed account";
    static constexpr double def_balance = 0.0;
    static constexpr double def_fee = 1.5;
public:
    CheckingAccount(std::string name = def_name, double balance = def_balance);
    // Inherited deposit
    bool withdraw(double amount);
};

#endif // _CHECKINGACCOUNT_H_
```

CheckingAccount.cpp:

```
#include "CheckingAccount.h"
#include "Account.h"
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

CheckingAccount::CheckingAccount(std::string name, double balance)
    : Account(name, balance) {}

bool CheckingAccount::withdraw(double amount) {
    amount += def_fee;
    return Account::withdraw(amount);
}

std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& out, const CheckingAccount& account) {
    out << "[CheckingAccount: " << account.name << ": " << account.balance << ", " << account.def_fee << " withdrawal fee]";
    return out;
}
```

TrustAccount.h:

```
#ifndef _TRUSTACCOUNT_H_
#define _TRUSTACCOUNT_H_
#include "SavingsAccount.h"
#include "Account.h"
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

class TrustAccount : public SavingsAccount {
    friend std::ostream& operator<< (std::ostream& out, const TrustAccount& account);
private:
    static constexpr const char* def_name = "Unnamed account";
    static constexpr double def_balance = 0.0;
    static constexpr double def_interest = 0.0; 
    static constexpr double def_bonus = 50.0;
    static constexpr double def_minimum = 0.2;
protected:
    int limit;
public:
    TrustAccount(std::string name = def_name, double balance = def_balance, double interest = def_interest, int limit = 0);
    bool deposit(double amount);
    bool withdraw(double amount);
};

#endif // _TRUSTACCOUNT_H_
```

TrustAccount.cpp:

```
#include "TrustAccount.h"
#include "SavingsAccount.h"
#include "Account.h"
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

TrustAccount::TrustAccount(std::string name, double balance, double interest, int limit)
    : SavingsAccount(name, balance, interest), limit{ 0 } {}

bool TrustAccount::deposit(double amount) {
    if (!SavingsAccount::deposit(amount))
        return false;
    if (amount >= 5000)
        Account::deposit(def_bonus);
    return true;
}

bool TrustAccount::withdraw(double amount) {
    if ((limit >= 3) || (amount > (balance * def_minimum)))
        return false;
    limit++;
    return SavingsAccount::withdraw(amount);
}

std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& out, const TrustAccount& account) {
    out << "[TrustAccount: " << account.name << ": " << account.balance << ", " << account.interest << "%, " << account.def_bonus << " deposit bonus, " << (3 - account.limit) << " withdrawals remaining]";
    return out;
}
```

Acctools is the part I use to facilitate displaying the code and testing it out. It just takes a vector of Account (and its derivatives) objects and mass-deposits/mass-withdraws/displays-all.

Acctools.h:

```
#ifndef _ACCTOOLS_H_
#define _ACCTOOLS_H_
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include "Account.h"
#include "SavingsAccount.h"
#include "CheckingAccount.h"
#include "TrustAccount.h"

// Accounts

void display(const std::vector<Account>& accounts);
void deposit(const std::vector<Account>& accounts, double balance);
void withdraw(const std::vector<Account>& accounts, double balance);

// SavingsAccounts

void display(const std::vector<SavingsAccount>& accounts);
void deposit(const std::vector<SavingsAccount>& accounts, double balance);
void withdraw(const std::vector<SavingsAccount>& accounts, double balance);

// CheckingAccounts

void display(const std::vector<CheckingAccount>& accounts);
void deposit(const std::vector<CheckingAccount>& accounts, double balance);
void withdraw(const std::vector<CheckingAccount>& accounts, double balance);

// TrustAccounts

void display(const std::vector<TrustAccount>& accounts);
void deposit(const std::vector<TrustAccount>& accounts, double balance);
void withdraw(const std::vector<TrustAccount>& accounts, double balance);

#endif // _ACCTOOLS_H_
```

Acctools.cpp:

```
#include "Acctools.h"
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include "Account.h"
#include "SavingsAccount.h"
#include "CheckingAccount.h"
#include "TrustAccount.h"

// Accounts
void display(const std::vector<Account>& accounts) {
    std::cout << "\n===Accounts========================================" << '\n';
    for (const auto& acc : accounts)
        std::cout << acc << '\n';
}

void deposit(std::vector<Account>& accounts, double amount) {
    std::cout << "\n===Depositing to Accounts========================================" << '\n';
    for (auto& acc : accounts)
        if (acc.deposit(amount))
            std::cout << "Deposited " << amount << " to " << acc << '\n';
        else
            std::cout << "Failed deposit of  " << amount << " to " << acc << '\n';
}

void withdraw(std::vector<Account>& accounts, double amount) {
    std::cout << "\n===Withdrawing from Accounts========================================" << '\n';
    for (auto& acc : accounts)
        if (acc.withdraw(amount))
            std::cout << "Withdrawn " << amount << " from " << acc << '\n';
        else
            std::cout << "Failed withdrawal of " << amount << " from " << acc << '\n';
}

// Savings Accounts

void display(const std::vector<SavingsAccount>& accounts) {
    std::cout << "\n===SavingsAccounts========================================" << '\n';
    for (const auto& acc : accounts)
        std::cout << acc << '\n';
}

void deposit(std::vector<SavingsAccount>& accounts, double amount) {
    std::cout << "\n===Depositing to SavingsAccounts========================================" << '\n';
    for (auto& acc : accounts)
        if (acc.deposit(amount))
            std::cout << "Deposited " << amount << " to " << acc << '\n';
        else
            std::cout << "Failed deposit of  " << amount << " to " << acc << '\n';
}

void withdraw(std::vector<SavingsAccount>& accounts, double amount) {
    std::cout << "\n===Withdrawing from SavingsAccounts========================================" << '\n';
    for (auto& acc : accounts)
        if (acc.withdraw(amount))
            std::cout << "Withdrawn " << amount << " from " << acc << '\n';
        else
            std::cout << "Failed withdrawal of " << amount << " from " << acc << '\n';
}

// Checking Accounts

void display(const std::vector<CheckingAccount>& accounts) {
    std::cout << "\n===CheckingAccounts========================================" << '\n';
    for (const auto& acc : accounts)
        std::cout << acc << '\n';
}

void deposit(std::vector<CheckingAccount>& accounts, double amount) {
    std::cout << "\n===Depositing to CheckingAccounts========================================" << '\n';
    for (auto& acc : accounts)
        if (acc.deposit(amount))
            std::cout << "Deposited " << amount << " to " << acc << '\n';
        else
            std::cout << "Failed deposit of  " << amount << " to " << acc << '\n';
}

void withdraw(std::vector<CheckingAccount>& accounts, double amount) {
    std::cout << "\n===Withdrawing from CheckingAccounts========================================" << '\n';
    for (auto& acc : accounts)
        if (acc.withdraw(amount))
            std::cout << "Withdrawn " << amount << " from " << acc << '\n';
        else
            std::cout << "Failed withdrawal of " << amount << " from " << acc << '\n';
}

// Trust Accounts

void display(const std::vector<TrustAccount>& accounts) {
    std::cout << "\n===TrustAccounts========================================" << '\n';
    for (const auto& acc : accounts)
        std::cout << acc << '\n';
}

void deposit(std::vector<TrustAccount>& accounts, double amount) {
    std::cout << "\n===Depositing to TrustAccounts========================================" << '\n';
    for (auto& acc : accounts)
        if (acc.deposit(amount))
            std::cout << "Deposited " << amount << " to " << acc << '\n';
        else
            std::cout << "Failed deposit of  " << amount << " to " << acc << '\n';
}

void withdraw(std::vector<TrustAccount>& accounts, double amount) {
    std::cout << "\n===Withdrawing from TrustAccounts========================================" << '\n';
    for (auto& acc : accounts)
        if (acc.withdraw(amount))
            std::cout << "Withdrawn " << amount << " from " << acc << '\n';
        else
            std::cout << "Failed withdrawal of " << amount << " from " << acc << '\n';
}
```

Finally, the main:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include "Acctools.h"
#include "Account.h"
#include "SavingsAccount.h"
#include "CheckingAccount.h"
#include "TrustAccount.h"


int main() {

    //////////////////////////////////////////////////// ACCOUNTS

    std::vector<Account> accounts;

    accounts.push_back(Account{ "Cata", 2000 });
    accounts.push_back(Account{ "Pernea", 0 });
    accounts.push_back(Account{ "Razvi", 4000 });

    display(accounts);

    deposit(accounts, 1000);

    display(accounts);

    withdraw(accounts, 3000);

    display(accounts);


    //////////////////////////////////////////////////// SAVINGS ACCOUNTS

    std::vector<SavingsAccount> savingsaccounts;

    savingsaccounts.push_back(SavingsAccount{ "Sapokee", 2000, 5.0 });
    savingsaccounts.push_back(SavingsAccount{ "Bernea", 0, 200.0 });
    savingsaccounts.push_back(SavingsAccount{ "Ravi", 4000, 1.0 });

    display(savingsaccounts);

    deposit(savingsaccounts, 1000);

    display(savingsaccounts);

    withdraw(savingsaccounts, 3000);

    display(savingsaccounts);

    //////////////////////////////////////////////////// CHECKING ACCOUNTS

    std::vector<CheckingAccount> checkingaccounts;

    checkingaccounts.push_back(CheckingAccount{ "Sapok", 2000 });
    checkingaccounts.push_back(CheckingAccount{ "Alex Bernea", 0 });
    checkingaccounts.push_back(CheckingAccount{ "Ravioli", 4000});

    display(checkingaccounts);

    deposit(checkingaccounts, 1000);

    display(checkingaccounts);

    withdraw(checkingaccounts, 3000);

    display(checkingaccounts);

    //////////////////////////////////////////////////// TRUST ACCOUNTS

    std::vector<TrustAccount> trustaccounts;

    trustaccounts.push_back(TrustAccount{ "Sapokee", 2000, 5.0 });
    trustaccounts.push_back(TrustAccount{ "Bernea", 0, 1.0 });
    trustaccounts.push_back(TrustAccount{ "Ravi", 4000, 1.0 });

    display(trustaccounts);

    deposit(trustaccounts, 5000);

    display(trustaccounts);

    withdraw(trustaccounts, 3000);

    display(trustaccounts);

    withdraw(trustaccounts, 100);

    display(trustaccounts);

    withdraw(trustaccounts, 100);

    display(trustaccounts);

    withdraw(trustaccounts, 100);

    display(trustaccounts);

    withdraw(trustaccounts, 100);

    display(trustaccounts);
}
```

Post answer edit:

Here's the better TrustAccount initialization:

```
private:
    // ... all other default values
    static constexpr int def_withdrawals = 0;
protected:
    int withdrawals; // changed the name to be more intuitive
public:
    TrustAccount(std::string name = def_name, double balance = def_balance, double interest = def_interest); // removed withdrawals from here

TrustAccount::TrustAccount(std::string name, double balance, double interest)
    : SavingsAccount(name, balance, interest), withdrawals{ def_withdrawals } {}
```

Comment: This doesn't address the question, but names that begin with an underscore followed by a capital letter (`_ACCOUNT_H_`) and names that contain two consecutive underscores are reserved for use by the implementation. Don't use them in your code.

Comment: Note that all the linker errors happen because of something the `main` function does and none of the missing symbols is actually a member of `Account` and they aren't shown anywhere in your code, whether as declaration or as definition...

Comment: It compiles clean for me with `-Wall -Wextra -pedantic-errors`. Are you sure you've added `Account.cpp` to the project? Edit: I just noticed the picture with the project setup. Ok, not that

Comment: *as inheritance usually works* and composition usually works better, but tell me, where is the inheritance in your example?

Comment: I get the feeling it might be a better idea to just include all the code, cause it doesn't seem like the whole picture is there

Comment: There, added. I hope it's okay now, and once again please excuse any stupid errors / common knowledge mistakes, I'm really not all that versed yet...

Comment: This is far from a [mre] though. You could minimize the amount of code (and keep checking that the error is still there).

Comment: @PeteBecker how would I go about using the include guard then? Is there a better way of declaring my header files for these sorts of implementations? Please let me know.

Comment: @TedLyngmo well, I'm actually really unsure on what the problem is here, so I really have no idea what code I could cut down on, so I really don't wanna risk cutting out an essential part of the code that actually produces the error, you know? Better safe than sorry, I guess

Comment: Focus on one of the errors. Since all of the errors seem to be of the same family, once you understand the problem with one, you'll probably understand the problem with all. Once you pick one, back up your code and throw out everything that isn't necessary to reproduce the error. This should be a `main` that calls that one function, an Acctools.cpp that contains the implementation of the one function and and Acctools.h that declares that one function. The rest is noise.

Comment: @Sapokee The good thing is that I could reproduce the error with those files. Your declarations in `Acctools.h` does not match the implementations. `void deposit(const std::vector<Account>& accounts, double balance);` vs. `void deposit(std::vector<Account>& accounts, double amount)` - notice the `const` in the declaration. That was just one of them though. Just go through them all and fix them.

Comment: That'd do it, for sure.

Comment: Holy crap, that did it. I can't believe it was just a misplaced const. That should be a lesson to me to be more careful when copying code over. Thanks to everyone that contributed!! And sorry for the dumb question...

Comment: My trick for problems like this is to open a simple text editor. Paste in the function declaration on one line. Paste in the start of the function definition on the next line. Try to line the two up. If you can't, the bit that's been added, missing, misspelled, whatever will be obvious.

Comment: @user4581301 thanks for the tip!

Comment: @Sapokee -- the include guard is just a name. You can pick anything you like; there's no magic there. Most people use all capital letters, and some variation of the name of the header.

Comment: @PeteBecker noted, will use something more fitting from now on :)

Comment: @Sapokee I noticed a potential bug while I looked at it: `TrustAccount::TrustAccount(std::string name, double balance, double interest, int limit) : SavingsAccount(name, balance, interest), limit{ 0 } {}` - notice that the `limit` argument given is ignored and the `limit` member variable is always initialized with `0`

Comment: @TedLyngmo so, just pick either the declaration default or the constructor default?

Comment: @Sapokee There is no _"constructor default"_. When the constructor executes, `limit` is always set to something. It may be set to the default value in the declaration (by the caller excluding that argument) or explicitly by the caller. Either way, it should probably be used, as in `TrustAccount::TrustAccount(std::string name, double balance, double interest, int limit) : SavingsAccount(name, balance, interest), limit{ limit } {}`

Comment: @TedLyngmo oh, I understand now; 

the initialization of "limit" to 0 was intended, as the user is supposed to only be able to withdraw 3 times, and they shouldn't be able to say how many times they can withdraw (I seem to have overlooked that aspect). I'll change it to "withdrawals" and use a static constexpr to initialize it to 0 instead, and also remove it from the constructor's expected arguments. Would that be a better way of going about it?

Comment: @Sapokee I didn't look into the logic of the program at all so it's hard to say but if you don't use the argument, yes, remove it. A `static` implies that you want the same rule to apply for _all_ instances though. Is that what you want? Sidenote: I ran the program with AddressSanitizer, UndefinedBehaviorSanitizer, LeakSanitizer and Valgrind. Nothing to report - clean 

Comment: @TedLyngmo in all honesty, I have no idea what any of those programs are, does it mean the code is optimized, or...?

Comment: @Sapokee It just means that the program was running (with the current data) without causing any problems w.r.t. leaking memory or stepping out of bounds of arrays and a lot more. It's a good thing!

Comment: @TedLyngmo updated with the example in the initial post, hope you get what I mean now

Comment: @Sapokee Yes, if you have a `constexpr` that you'd like to give a name, that looks fine. Is there a way to supply a different value for `withdrawals`  than `def_withdrawals`? One could argue that when starting (constructing) an account, the number of withdrawals should always be `0` so it wouldn't be surprising to see `withdrawals{0}`.

Comment: @TedLyngmo well the initial number of withdrawals should always be 0, but I added the `constexpr` to make it a little easier to read and to easily change any instances of the default withdrawals from one place. There isn't really a need to change the value of `withdrawals` after initialization manually so I don't think anything should be added there.

Comment: @Sapokee No, making newly constructed accounts with withdrawals != 0 would sound a bit strange :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your declarations of the `deposit` and `withdraw` overloads in `Acctools.h` have `const` on the `std::vector` of the account type.

The fix is to remove `const` so that the declarations matches the definitions in `Acctools.cpp`:

```
#ifndef _ACCTOOLS_H_
#define _ACCTOOLS_H_
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include "Account.h"
#include "SavingsAccount.h"
#include "CheckingAccount.h"
#include "TrustAccount.h"

// Accounts

void display(const std::vector<Account>& accounts);
void deposit(std::vector<Account>& accounts, double balance);
void withdraw(std::vector<Account>& accounts, double balance);

// SavingsAccounts

void display(const std::vector<SavingsAccount>& accounts);
void deposit(std::vector<SavingsAccount>& accounts, double balance);
void withdraw(std::vector<SavingsAccount>& accounts, double balance);

// CheckingAccounts

void display(const std::vector<CheckingAccount>& accounts);
void deposit(std::vector<CheckingAccount>& accounts, double balance);
void withdraw(std::vector<CheckingAccount>& accounts, double balance);

// TrustAccounts

void display(const std::vector<TrustAccount>& accounts);
void deposit(std::vector<TrustAccount>& accounts, double balance);
void withdraw(std::vector<TrustAccount>& accounts, double balance);

#endif // _ACCTOOLS_H_
```